# How to create a local QnA maker knowledgebase for a Microsoft bot?

Tags: node.js, localhost, botframework, bots, azure-qna-maker

I am trying to develop a chat bot using Microsoft bot framework V4 and language as Node.js but don't want to deploy in Azure rather than want to keep it to my **local machine**.

As **I don't want Azure**, I am unable to create **QnA maker knowledgebase** without Azure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no such way to create a Knowledge Base without creating the QnAMaker resources on Azure. You must first set up a QnA Maker service in Azure before creating a knowledge base. The QnAMaker resource manages the knowledge base content. Without the QnAMaker resource and the authoring and endpoint keys, you cannot use the Azure Cognitive Service or make a call to the knowledge base.

Please refer to the following [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/how-to/set-up-qnamaker-service-azure) for more details.

Comment: Can you please accept the answer so that it helps others as well with a similar query? Thanks